# How to plot an cylindrical coordinates equation in cartesian

Tags: matlab

I have this equation `r=z*cos(theta)` and I need to plot it in Cartesian coordinates in Matlab. How can I do this?

Comment: 1) Telling 'this is very urgent' in your question won't make people want to set aside everything they do to come help you solve your problem. 2) This is a 'Let me Google that for you' question, i.e. a Google search would tell you your answer in less time than it took to write your question. 3) Look at this link, it gives the answer: http://www.geom.uiuc.edu/docs/reference/CRC-formulas/node42.html

Answer (score 2):

First off, the definition of your cylindrical co-ordinates is wrong.  Given the azimuthal sweep around the `z` axis `theta` as well as the radius of the cylinder `r`, the Cartesian co-ordinates within a cylinder is defined as:

```
x = r*cos(theta)
y = r*sin(theta)
z = z
```

Therefore, you would need to define a grid of co-ordinates for `r`, `theta` and `z`, use these co-ordinates and plug them into the above code, then draw them.  I would recommend you use [`plot3`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plot3.html) as you want to plot 3D points in Cartesian space.  Also, use [`meshgrid`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/meshgrid.html) to define your grid of points.

As such, the radius of a cylinder is (usually) constant when you're drawing it, and `theta` and `z` are the quantities you are varying.  Let's assume that `-2 <= z <= 2` and `r = 2`.  We know that to create a cylinder, we have to sweep around a circle from `0 <= theta <= 2*pi`.  Therefore, do something like this:

```
%// Define (r,theta,z)
[theta, z] = meshgrid(0:0.001:2*pi, -2:0.001:2);
r = 2*ones(size(theta));

%// Calculate x and y.  z was calculated earlier
x = r.*cos(theta);
y = r.*sin(theta);

%// Plot the points
plot3(x(:), y(:), z(:), 'b.');
grid;
view(-48,60); %// Adjust viewing angle
```

---

This is what I get:

[image]

---

You can certainly use more efficient techniques, like what Kamtal has suggested with `pol2cart`, but you said you wanted the actual Cartesian co-ordinates, and so `x`, `y` and `z` contains those co-ordinates in 3D space for you.  I'm assuming you want these for further processing.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

```
n = linspace(-pi,pi,20);
m = linspace(0,1,20);
[theta,z] = meshgrid(n,m);
r = z .* cos(theta);
[X,Y,Z] = pol2cart(theta,r,z); 
surf(X,Y,Z)
axis equal
```

[image]

If you change it to `r = 1 .* cos(theta);` then you will get a cylinder,

[image]